# How to step through a shell script line-by-line and send each line to the terminal?

Tags: macos, emacs

I have an `.sh` file with shell commands, for example:

```
echo "What shall are we running?"
if [ "$0" == "-bash" ]; then
    echo "I'm running a bash"
else
    echo "Not a bash"
fi
ls -al | less
htop
```

I'd like to step through such files one line at a time (for teaching purposes)
in Emacs (27.2) and send each line to the macOS (12.1) terminal application `Terminal.app`.

The post most closely related to this seems to be
[this](https://superuser.com/questions/440294/send-command-to-terminal-from-emacs) but
none of the solutions works well. For example, using `tmux` inside `Terminal.app`, combined with `emamux` doesn't work since the latter doesn't allow to
send full lines (and the solution with `tmux` has some disadvantages besides being
overkill). The least upvoted answer [here](https://github.com/haberdashPI/iterm.el/blob/master/iterm.el) presents an idea for iTerm. The most important function
is `iterm-send-string`, but I have no experience programming in Emacs Lisp, so
couldn't get this to work.

Another idea I found is `eepitch`, but I don't want to convolute my shell
script with other input (again, for teaching purposes). And yet another idea is [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/execute-current-line-in-shell), but for GNU/Linux.

A frequent answer to such questions seems to be "Why not M-x (e)shell?"
What works best so far is indeed `M-x ansi-term`, combined with
[this approach](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48472/how-to-make-m-x-ansi-term-behave-like-m-x-shell-opening-in-new-window). The problem is that neither `shell`, `eshell` nor `ansi-term` are
equivalent to `Terminal.app`, for example the last two lines in the
above example shell script (`less`, `htop`) won't work in an `ansi-term`.
So my best solution for now is to step through 'most' of the lines in the
shell script in `ansi-term` and occasionally pull up `Terminal.app` to
execute commands that don't work in `ansi-term`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented with an AppleScript script to send commands to the terminal. This worked, but talking to AppleScript from Emacs didn't. After a longer search, I came across `vterm` [here](https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm), which is a different solution than I expected but a nicer one as `vterm` can be run in an Emacs buffer. So my solution is this:

1. Install `vterm`. For me this was `brew install cmake libvterm`, then `M-x list-packages` (=> install `vterm`).
2. In `.emacs` I have `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c v") #'vterm-other-window)` and then the following (straightforward adaption of [this post's solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50539/sending-code-to-an-ansi-term-via-isend-mode-how-to-modify-default-buffer-chosen?rq=1)):

   ```
    (defun isend-with-vterm ()
      (interactive)
      (let ((term-buf (get-buffer "*vterm*")))
        (unless term-buf
          (display-buffer
           (save-window-excursion
             (save-current-buffer
               (setq term-buf (vterm (or explicit-shell-file-name
                                         (getenv "ESHELL")
                                         shell-file-name)))))))
        (isend-associate (buffer-name term-buf))))
    (define-key global-map [C-return] 'isend-with-vterm)

    (defun isend-dissociate-on-kill (buffer-name)
      (let ((buf (get-buffer buffer-name))
            (orig-buffer (current-buffer)))
        (with-current-buffer buf
          (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook
                    `(lambda ()
                       (with-current-buffer ,orig-buffer
                         (isend-mode -1)))
                    nil t))))
    (advice-add 'isend-associate :after #'isend-dissociate-on-kill)
   ```

3. This allows to start a `vterm` via `C-c v`, and then I can send the current line to `vterm` from the code buffer (e.g. some `.sh` file) via repeated `C-RET`. The main point is that `vterm` is much more capable than `shell`, `eshell` or `ansi-term`.

If you don't want to mess with `.emacs`, then simply do `M-x vterm-other-window`, then (from the `.sh` file) do `M-x isend-associate + RET + *vterm* + RET` and you get the same functionality.